# Apache POI Cell Style Error - style not set

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have this chunk of (slightly modified for SO) code I inherited:

```
public String generateExcel(ExportData export) throws ApplicationException {
    String fileName = "<fileName>";
            
    try {
        
        String exportFile = new StringBuilder().append(fileName).toString();
    
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(exportFile.toString(),false);
        
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        
        CellStyle headerStyle = <function to create header style>;
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
        wb.setSheetName(0, "Export");
        
        int currentRow = 1; 
        
        // Header
        Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(currentRow);
        currentRow++;
        
        int headerCell = 0;
        for (String dataId : export.getColumns()) {
            Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(headerCell);
            headerCell++;
            cell.setCellValue( export.getColumns().get(dataId) );
            cell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
        }

        for (BaseModel model : export.getDataList()) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(currentRow);
            currentRow++;

            int currentCell = 0;
            for (String dataIdx : export.getColumns()) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(currentCell);
                Object o = model.get(dataIdx);

                if (o instanceof Integer) {
                    cell.setCellValue( Misc.toDouble( (Integer)o ) );
                } else if (o instanceof Timestamp) {
                    cell.setCellValue( Misc.toDate( (Timestamp) o ) );
                    cell.getCellStyle().setDataFormat( HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("m/d/yy h:mm") );
                } else if (o instanceof Date) {
                    cell.setCellValue( (Date) o );
                    cell.getCellStyle().setDataFormat( HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("m/d/yy") );
                } else {
                    String s = ( o != null ) ? o.toString() : "";
                    cell.setCellValue( s );
                }
                
                HSSFCellStyle wrappedCellStyle = w.createCellStyle();
                wrappedCellStyle.setWrapText(true);
                cell.setCellStyle(wrappedCellStyle); - **here**
                
                
                currentCell++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < headerCell ; i++) {
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(i, true);
        }
        
        wb.write(fos);
        fos.close();
    
        return fileName;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ApplicationException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

What it basically does is is that it reads the ExportData object and writes it to the excel file with a specific name, row by row.
First it begins with the header.
Then it inserts the data column by column and set some styling if necessary.

For the most part, this works.

At the line I marked as "***here***", from what I've seen, this will overwrite the original cell styles and replaces it with one where the text will wrap for each cell only.
An issue, but not the main point and is still acceptable for now.

**The problem is, after a certain number of loops, the styling just stops replacing. Why?
The excel file will still generate as usual, and there doesnt seem to be any data issues, and I can still open the file no problem. But on reading the generated file, there's a notable part where the formatting just stops.**

As mentioned, I know the line is problematic, but, for now, my sample data only prints out, according to `HSSFWorkbook.getNumCellStyles()`, roughly around 300 unique styles, a far cry from the 64k limit I heard Excel has, so it doesnt seem to have an exception with regards to that.
(on that note, I did fix the initial issue so that the style is declared outside the loop and this leads to the proper output and a lesser count of unique styles, but my main question here is why did it happen in the first place)

I've made a few printout statements using `o.toString()` and `DataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell)` before and after the line to verify the expected cell output; they all show the expected results.

I tried moving the problematic lines above the `if` statements so that the styles doesnt get overwritten, but gets added on to and it's a similar issue...just reversed (my correct styling works to a certain extent, then it stops.

I suspect that *something* might have happened during the `wb.write(fos)` process, but I cant verify it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71412798/cell-style-is-lost-or-not-displayed-in-excel-97-2003-xls/71419505#71419505

Comment: @AxelRichter is there a proper source on that? It makes sense, but I would also like to read abit more in detailed on it.

Comment: See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/cell-style-is-lost-or-not-displayed-in-excel-97/e32b0006-a036-4824-a9f1-8ef4b0f8ef4f.  The "Volunteer Moderator" only copy/pasted my code from  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71412798/cell-style-is-lost-or-not-displayed-in-excel-97-2003-xls/71419505#71419505. So my answer is Microsofts answer too ;-).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cell style is lost or not displayed in Excel 97-2003 (.xls)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71412798/cell-style-is-lost-or-not-displayed-in-excel-97-2003-xls) (marking this as duplicate)

Comment: @OlafKock Both yes and no. It's something, but is not as deep an answer I would like. The Microsoft Moderator in the other link mentions that '''(the code) creates the style and then apply the style to the cell and at the end the style is destroyed, that might be the general issue.''' and even that answer feels unfinished.